# Relation between sum of indicators and average of probability for independent sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ be independent events, set $N_n := \sum_{i=1}^n I_{A_i}$ and $\overline p_n := n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)$, then
>   $$
>  P\left( \lim_n \left( n^{-1} N_n - \overline p_n \right) = 0 \right) = 1
> $$
>   i.e. $n^{-1} N_n - \overline p_n$ converges to $0$ in probability.

Any hints how to solve this? I tried to show that $P(|n^{-1} N_n - \overline p_n| \ge \varepsilon \mbox{ i.o} ) = 0$ for each $\varepsilon > 0$ by using Borel-Cantelli's first lemma, thereby I have to show that $\sum_{n} P(|n^{-1} N_n - \overline p_n| \ge \varepsilon) < \infty$, so I tried to find an upper bound for $P(|n^{-1} N_n - \overline p_n| \ge \varepsilon)$. With $E[N_n] = n\overline p_n$ and $V[N_n] = E[N_n^2] - (n\overline p_n)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i) (1 - P(A_i))$ [here I used independence] the best I get is
$$
 P(|n^{-1} N_n - \overline p_n| \ge \varepsilon)
 \le \frac{V[N_2]}{n^2 \varepsilon^2} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i) (1 - P(A_i))}{n^2\varepsilon}
$$
but here I am stuck, so could anybody help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your statement : $$P\left( \lim_n \left( n^{-1} N_n - \overline p_n \right) = 0 \right) = 1 $$ means that $ n^{-1} N_n - \overline p_n $ converge $a.s.$ to $0$. If you want to show that $n^{-1} N_n - \overline p_n \to 0$ in probability you only have to show that for any $\varepsilon >0$ $$ P(|n^{-1} N_n - \overline p_n |>\varepsilon )\to 0 \text{ when } n\to \infty.$$
But you have already shown that $\lim _n P(|n^{-1} N_n - \overline p_n| \ge \varepsilon)=0$ because $\sum _{i=1}^n P(A_i)(1-P(A_i))\leq n$.

Comment: Yes, I confused both notions, convergence a.s. is not the same as convergence in probability, thank you!